# Pigeonhole principle for coprime numbers

Tags: combinatorics

For a set of $n+1$ integers in $[2n]$, I would like to show that there always exist two coprime ones.  This seems like a classic pigeonhole problem but I'm not sure what the pigeons or holds are.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One can use the pigeonhole principle to show that there are always two numbers next to each other.  These must necessarily be coprime.