# Let A be a subset of {1, 2, 3 ... 2n-1, 2n} containing n + 1 elements. (Full Question below)

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations, pigeonhole-principle

*Let A be a subset of {1, 2, 3 ... 2n-1, 2n} containing n + 1 elements Show that:*

- *a) some two elements of a are relatively prime*
- *b) some two elements of a have the property that one divides the other*

I am assuming that we have to use the pigeon-hole principle here but I have no idea how to use it in this particular situation.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2818921/pigeonhole-principle-for-coprime-numbers and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3533489/pigeonhole-principle-for-numbers-and-their-divisors-within-a-set

Comment: I got the $a$ part but how do you prove the $b$ part?

Comment: I linked two questions. Here is one more https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/315050/using-pigeonhole-principle-to-prove-two-numbers-in-a-subset-of-2n-divide-eac, and even more in the "linked questions" in that question.